# handle head of binary search tree in nested structure

Tags: c

i have to create binary search tree. so i have used nested structure. i am not able to maintain head of the tree. when i give inputs then it is creating new node of every input. Help me with how to handle Head.

tree.h

```
#ifndef __TREE__H__
#define __TREE__H__

typedef struct _BSTNode
{
  int data;
  struct _BSTNode *left,*right;
}BSTNode;

typedef struct _BST
{
  BSTNode *tHead;
}BST;

int insertBST(BST ,int);

#endif
```

mainTree.c

```
#include"tree.h"
#include<stdio.h>



int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  BST bst;
  bst.tHead=NULL;
  int element;
  fp = fopen("input","r");


  while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&element)!=EOF)
    {
      insertBST(bst,element);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

insertBST.c

```
#include"tree.h"
#include<stdio.h>


int insertBST(BST bst,int element)
{
  return _insertBST(bst.tHead,NULL,element);
}


int _insertBST(BSTNode *p,BSTNode *parent,int e)
{
  if(p==NULL)
    return createBST(p,e);
  if(p->data == e)
    return 0;
  if(p->data < e)
    return _insertBST(p->right,p,e);
  if(p->data > e)
    return _insertBST(p->left,p,e);
  return -1;
 }
```

createBST.c

```
#include"tree.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int createBST(BSTNode *p,int element)
{
  BSTNode *node = (BSTNode *)malloc(sizeof(BSTNode));
  node->data = element;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

    if(p== NULL)
    {
      p=node;
      fprintf(stdout,"Im here 1");
      return 0;
      }
    else
   {
      if(p->data < node ->data)
    (p->left) = node;
         fprintf(stdout,"Im here 2");
     return 0;
      if(p->data > node ->data)
    (p->right) = node;
          fprintf(stdout,"Im here 3");
      return 0;
   }
}
```

output:-

```
@:~/Ds/tree$gcc mainTree.c insertBST.c createBST.c
@:~/Ds/tree$ ./a.out
Im here 1Im here 1Im here 1Im here 1Im here 1
```

input :- 40 10 30 20

Comment: How your functions are defined, `bst` is passed by value. and so is `bst._tHead`. Both are incorrect, and are situations which require you pass the intended target of a potential update by address or utilize function return values to pass back potential updates. Learning to pass addresses to utilize out-parameter semantics in a pass-by-value language like C is a common road bump, so don't kick yourself too hard.

Comment: I am unable to handle the head of the tree
and it must be handled by using call by reference